# Blender motion tracking track marks not showing pixel error

Tags: tracking

Maybe a dumb question, but when motion tracking why aren't all my markers showing the solve pixel error?

If i've got around ten active at one time as an example, maybe one or two show their pixel error, all the others don't. Info option is on under view settings. Makes fine tuning the solve next to impossible.

Comment: did you select all the markers when you started the track?

Comment: Yes. The majority when clicking on them state "track no : tracked locked" It was the same when they were unlocked they didn't show their individual pixel errors. For some reason now, the motion tracking > tracking > dope sheet window is also blank with no tracking marker info in it at all despite the file having around 80 tracking markers in it in total...